# Cant run liquibase with command line

Tags: java, database, migration, liquibase

I want to use liquibase but when I want to let it run with command line this happens:

```
PS C:\Users\Ferid\Downloads\liquibase-3.6.0-bin> .\liquibase
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/filter/Filter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

I have tried liquibase-3.6.1 and now liquibase-3.6.0

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One of the required libraries is missing from the library folder.

See the bug report link below where another user had the same issue.

> It appears 3.6.1 is still missing slf4j-api-1.7.25 in the lib folder
>   and I still receive an error invoking liquibase via cli.

You have three options:

1. Get the library yourself [[here]](https://www.slf4j.org/download.html).
2. Wait for the patched
   version (Maybe submit a fix yourself).
3. Revert to an older version (3.5.5 Should work)

See here for the bug report:
https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3201

Comment: Bug is still open even in 3.6.2 https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3222

Answer (score 5):

You must add this libraries to your classpath:

- [logback-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.2.3)
- [logback-clasic](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3)

In my case I am using Spring Boot liquibase integration, so, here is my `build.gradle` liquibase configutarion

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1211.jre7'
        classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "org.liquibase.gradle" version "2.0.1"
}


dependencies {
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1211.jre7'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.6.3'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:2.0.1'
    liquibaseRuntime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3'
    liquibaseRuntime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
}

def changeLog = "$projectDir/src/main/db/changelog.xml"
liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            changeLogFile changeLog
            url 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/postgres'
            username 'postgres'
            password 'postgres'
        }
    }
}
```

It's an extract from [liquibase-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin)

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon the same issue in version `3.6.2`. The problem is that Liquibase can't find the required classes (`ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter` being just one of them, but there are others). There is no universal recipe, but the high-level idea is to found JARs the required classes live in and feed them to the `-cp` command-line parameter. Looks a bit ugly but this is what finally worked:

```
#!/bin/bash

M2_REPO=/home/raiks/.m2/repository
LIQUIBASE_CMDLINE='liquibase.integration.commandline.Main --changeLogFile=~/changelog-master.xml update'
# Feed all the required JARs to -cp
JAVA_CMD="java -cp $M2_REPO/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.6.2/liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:$M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:$M2_REPO/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:$M2_REPO/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar $LIQUIBASE_CMDLINE"
echo $JAVA_CMD
eval $JAVA_CMD
```

Please note that I use `:` on Linux while `;` will be required on Windows. Adjust the command according to your specific JAR location.

Alternatively, you can put dependencies to a directory and specify it with a wildcard after `-cp`:

```
   $ java -cp "/home/raiks/liquibase-deps/*" liquibase.integration.commandline.Main --changeLogFile=~/changelog-master.xml update
```