# ClassNotFoundException running Liquibase standalone on command line

Tags: java, liquibase

I want to run Liquibase standalone (i.e. w/o "installation") on the command line. However, whatever I tried I'm getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.Context` or some other logback class.

I checked the Liquibase `pom.xml` to find out exactly which dependencies it needs and provided them accordingly.

**1. attempt**

```
java -jar liquibase-core-3.8.6.jar \
     -cp jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:snakeyaml-1.24.jar:slf4j-api-1.7.28.jarlogback-core-1.2.3.jar::logback-classic-1.2.3.jar \
     --classpath=backend/target/mywar.war \
     --changeLogFile=db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

**2. and further attempts**

I understand that `-cp` is the regular classpath parameter for the `java` command and `--classpath` is a program argument for Liquibase as per [the documentation](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html). Yet, I still tried various combinations of parameters of the 1st attempt but to no avail.

Comment: my understanding is this, you first install liquibase so that it can be added in classpath, after that run command liquibase [options] [command]

Comment: maybe a typo in the `-cp` parameter? `:` missing between `slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar` and `logback-core-1.2.3.jar`

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487054/cant-run-liquibase-with-command-line.

Comment: liquibase [options] [command] corresponds to liquibase
--classpath=mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar
--url="jdbc:mysql://"
--changeLogFile=db.changelog-1.0.xml
--username=<MYSQL USERNAME>
--password=<MYSQL PASSWORD>

Comment: above mentioned options are necessary to specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arghh, silly me. With all the IDE magic these days you forget how to start a Java program on the CLI.

You can't combine `-jar` and `-cp` i.e. you can't put additional JARs on the classpath with `-jar`.

So, to fix this you need to `java -cp ... liquibase.integration.commandline.Main --classpath=...`.